# When do the spindle fibers attach to the chromosome

Tags: genetics, cell-biology

At what phase does this occur in mitosis (or even meiosis); some text books say prophase while others say metaphase.

Comment: Would you like quoting which book said what?

Comment: Happens in prometaphase.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion comes from the inconsistent terminology in the literature. The attachement of the spindles to the chromosomes happens in the **Prometaphase** [[1](https://books.google.de/books?id=Cg4WAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=essential%20cell%20biology&hl=de&pg=PA624#v=onepage&q&f=false), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometaphase)]. The name already suggests that this is not one of the classical phases is cell division, but lies somewhere between Pro- and metaphase. Wikipedia states:

> *Prometaphase is sometimes simply included as part of the end of prophase and early metaphase.*

If you really need to stick to the classical scheme of pro-, meta-, ana- and telophase, I would personally suggest to treat the attachement (not the formation!) of spindles as a part of the metaphase.